# Power button IRremote

Tags: arduino

I am creating 3 LEDs that will light up by a remote. I am able to light up the LEDs individually but I need the power button to shut off all of the LEDs. How can I create a 4th case to turn off all LEDs?

```js
#include <IRremote.h>
 
int RECV_PIN = 3; // the pin where you connect the output pin of TSOP4838
int led1 = 2;
int led2 = 4;
int led3 = 7;
int itsONled[] = {0,0,0,0};
/* the initial state of LEDs is OFF (zero) 
the first zero must remain zero but you can 
change the others to 1's if you want a certain
led to light when the board is powered */
#define code1  12495 // code received from button A
#define code2  6375 // code received from button B
#define code3  31365 // code received from button C
 
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
 
decode_results results;
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // you can comment this line
  irrecv.enableIRIn();  // Start the receiver
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
}
 
void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    unsigned int value = results.value;
    switch(value) {
       case code1:
         if(itsONled[1] == 1) {        // if first led is on then
            digitalWrite(led1, LOW);   // turn it off when button is pressed
            itsONled[1] = 0;           // and set its state as off
         } else {                      // else if first led is off
             digitalWrite(led1, HIGH); // turn it on when the button is pressed
             itsONled[1] = 1;          // and set its state as on
         }
          break; 
       case code2:
         if(itsONled[2] == 1) {
            digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
            itsONled[2] = 0;
         } else {
             digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
             itsONled[2] = 1;
         }
          break;
       case code3:
         if(itsONled[3] == 1) {
            digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
            itsONled[3] = 0;
         } else {
             digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
             itsONled[3] = 1;
         }
          break;          
    }
    Serial.println(value); // you can comment this line
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a library within the arduino IDE conflict with each other. Have you tried https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/issues/98#issuecomment-63214330 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino error : TKD2 was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008961/arduino-error-tkd2-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: how do you delete a library